# Qt: How to correct grabbing invisible/hidden widgets?

Tags: c++, qt, screen-grab

I need to grab a widget in order to save it as an image file. I use the following code:

```
QPixmap img = this->webView->grab();
img.save("image.PNG);
```

This doesn't work though when the application has been minimized or the grabbed widget is a child of *QStackedWidget* or *QTabWidget*.

Please, help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
QPushButton button("123");
button.resize(100, 100);
button.hide();    

QPixmap p(button.size());
button.render(&p);
p.save("1.png");
```

Comment: I try that, before questing, but it don't work :(
At now, i use next workaround:
# Create new Widget

Comment: Can you post some more code? This tiny example works fine. Looks like smth wrong may be in another place.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I try it before questing, but not working. Now i use next workaround:
1. Create widget with attributes Qt::WA_DontShowOnScreen | Qt::WA_ShowWithoutActivating | Qt::WA_AlwaysOnTop;
2. Move webView widget to new widget;
3. grabbing from new widget;
4. moving webView to back in QTabWidget

Maybe Qt have special flags or attributes like as Qt::WA_DrawWhenMinimized?